# Failure on python dataframe to sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

My problem is in python with sqlite3
for some tables this error occured.
I use this syntax but I encounter with this error again df.to_sql('table1',condb,if_exists='append',index=False)

sqlite3.OperationalError: table "table1" already exists

Comment: You sytax appears to be correct. Are you trying to append to a normal table, not a view? Did  you try and restart your system? Is the dataframe structure similar to to existing table? What version is pandas on your system? How about sqlite3?

Comment: I solved the problem. My table in database is Tabl1 but in script i wrote table1. So this error is raised